# UpdateAPIView | Django REST does not update data properly

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to register values in a table of relations when updating data. Conversely, I want to generate an error if the value does not exist.

models.py

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True,
                            editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    role = models.OneToOneField('Role', related_name='user',
                                blank=True, null=True,
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ommited...

class Role(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug
```

serializers.py

```py
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers

from accounts.models import CustomUser, Role


class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('slug',)


class UserSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    role = RoleSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('uuid', 'email', 'role', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

views.py

```py
class UserUpdateView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Role DB Table

```
id:1 | slug:admin
```

## Expectation

Request(PATCH) Parameter

```
{
    "role":{
        "slug":"foo"
    }
}

# error: foo does not exist in the Role table
```

```
{
    "role":{
        "slug":"admin"
    }
}

# OK!!!
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can you share what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class UserSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='slug', queryset=Role.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('uuid', 'email', 'role', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

In this case request should be unnested:

```
{
    "role":"foo"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment

First, when I tried using SlugRelatedField as you suggested, I got the following error.

Comment: AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`.

Comment: So I added read_only=`True`.

Comment: class UserSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='slug', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('uuid', 'email', 'role', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)

Comment: Request (PATCH) Parameter

Comment: {
    “role” : “foo”
}

Comment: ERROR : django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Comment: @i'mfat. this field shouldn't be read only. Instead you need to specify queryset parameter for `SlugRelatedField`. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your early comments.

I tried using SlugRelatedField() in combination with queryset and now I get this error

IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed:

However, this is different from this question, so I will try to improve one by one.

I will also post the solution when everything is perfect.

Thank you very much.